# Can't get .map() working in React Native render()

Tags: react-native

How can I get this to work, {showExamples} isn't showing any output. The full source code is here: https://rnplay.org/apps/t2E4Ig

```
var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var showExamples = examples.map(function(value){
                return (
            <View>
                {value.render}
            </View>
          );
            });

    return (
        <View>

        <Image
          source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
          style={styles.base}
        />

        {showExamples}

        </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `render` property on each of the example items is a function, so you need to invoke it with `{value.render()}`, instead of trying to "render a function: with `{value.render}`.

Comment: I keep making this mistake, as soon as I went to sleep I realized I needed the (). It was horrible though to not get any errror, or visual that I was don't something wrong. I guess I should start using a debugger, however I was in www.rnplay.org -)

Comment: Side note, I would of thought just `value.render` should display the contents of the function i.e. the source code. As it does in the browser console. Type `foo = function() {return "fooy fun";}` into a JS REPL, then `foo` and you see source code. My React Native app should of showed source no?

Comment: @GiantElk I'm not sure how that is expected to behave, but in either case, you cannot render text directly into `View`, but you must wrap it in a `Text` element.

Comment: You are correct. I should of put more code up, `{value.render()}` is a function that returns a valid React Native component. Check it out here: https://rnplay.org/apps/t2E4Ig

Comment: Actually, I meant that if you expected to see the stringified source code of the `value.render` function, you would have needed to have wrapped it with a `Text` element. And that is assuming that React Native automatically calls `toString` on objects given to Text, which I don't know if it does.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. @jevakallio Would be nice if React Native could still somehow throw an error or warning. No visual feedback sucks.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this.

```
var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render() {

   return (
    <View>

      <Image
        source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
      style={styles.base}
      />

     {
       examples.map(function(value, i){
            return (
              <View key={i}>
                {value.render}
             </View>
           );
        })
     }

    </View>
);
```

}
});

Comment: Please give more detail as to what the OP did wrong and how your code corrects it. Posting code-only answers in SO is frowned upon, as it does not help others as much as it would if there is an explanation of the answer.

Comment: I don't have `key` but can't see any errors in www.rnplay.org, once I start using xCode will know for sure. The actual fix is calling the function `value.render()` as opposed to a reference to the function.